# Solving for $x$ in $y=x^x(\ln x + 1)$ (Lambert W?)

Tags: special-functions, exponentiation, lambert-w

I made a bunch of problems exercising the Lambert W-function in the solution, because I like to exercise to new concepts that I learn about. One that I came up with was rearranging $y = x^x(\ln x + 1)$, i.e. the derivative of $x^x$, for $x$. Is it even possible to do so, or do all the $x$'s make it too complex for even $W$?

I tried approaching it like I did for $y = x \ln x - x$ (the integral of $\ln x$), which involved trying to factor something out, but I quickly found myself running in circles. My scraps of an attempt at $y = x^x(\ln x + 1)$ follow.

$$\begin{align}
y &= x^x(\ln x + 1) \\
&= e^{x \ln x}(\ln x + 1) \\
&= e^{x \ln x}e^{\ln(\ln x + 1)} \\
&= e^{x \ln x + \ln(\ln x + 1)} \\
\ln y &= x \ln x + \ln(\ln x + 1) \\\\
&\qquad\text{???}
\end{align}$$

Comment: What do you mean by solving? Get $x$ in terms of $y$?

Comment: I don't believe $x^x (\log x+1)$ has an elementary inverse, if that's what you mean.

Comment: You can rearrange into $e^y=e^{(y+1)e^{ye^y}},y=e^x$ which is almost $w^{w^w}$

Comment: @IV_ The comment said “almost $w^{w^w}$”. It probably cannot be rearranged into that form.

Answer (score 0):

For applying only Lambert W and elementary functions, your equation should be in the form

$$f_1(f_2(x)e^{f_2(x)})=c,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

where $c$ constant and $f_1$ and $f_2$ are elementary functions with a suitable elementary partial inverse. Unfortunately your equation doesn't seem to be able to be brought into this form.

Answer (score 0):

[Lagrange inversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInversionTheorem.html) gives:

$$y=x^x(\ln(x)+1)\mathop\implies^{x=e^w} y^{-1}=e^{-1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}e^w\left(\frac{(w+1)}{e^{we^w}(w+1)}\right)^n\right|_{-1}$$

Now use Maclaurin series and [general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule):

$$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}e^{w-nwe^w}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-n)^m}{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}w^me^{(m+1)w}}{dw^{n-1}}= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-n)^m}{n!}\binom{n-1}k\frac{d^kw^m}{dw^k}\frac{d^{n-1-k} e^{(m+1)w} }{dw^{n-1-k}}$$

Evaluating derivatives and summing over $k$ gives [Laguerre L](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/LaguerreL3General/):

$$x=\frac{dy^y}{dy}\implies y=\frac1e-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^nn^{m-1}}{e^{m+1}m!}\operatorname L_{n-1}^{m-n+1}(m+1)$$

[shown](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=exp%28-1.0%29-sum%5Bsum%5B%281%2F3%29%5En+%28e%5E%28-1+-+m%29++n%5E%28m-1%29+%28-1%29%5En+LaguerreL%28n-1%2C1%2Bm-n%2Cm%2B1%29%29%2F%28m%21%29%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C50%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C50%7D%5D) [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5By%5Ey%5D%3D1%2F3) with both sums interchangeable. There does not seem to be a way to expand the Laguerre function as an integral to get an integral representation of $y^{-1}$